# Increase button text visibility even after the button is disabled

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Inside lightning component I have a button.

```
<aura:attribute name="disableShowMe" type="Boolean"/>
    <lightning:button variant="base" label="showMe" title="showMe" disabled="{!v.disableShowMe}" onclick="{!c.handleClick}"
```

Based upon some logic in code I am disabling the button. so the user cannot see button text which is expected behaviour. But is there a way even after I disable the button I still want to make the button Text a little bolder so user can at least see the button text even though it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<lightning:button/>` you can use `<button style="color:black !important"  class="slds-button" disabled="true">Button</button>` as you can implement inline css as per your requirements